# Override FOSUserBundle Cotroller

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I can't override `ResettingController` of `FOSUser`.
`ProfileController` and `RegistrationController` work, but `ResettingController` not.

AppBundle.php:

```
namespace AppBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
   {
    return 'FOSUserBundle';
   }
}
```

AppBundle\Controller\ResettingFOSUser1Controller:

```
 namespace AppBundle\Controller;

 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
 use Sonata\UserBundle\Controller\ResettingFOSUser1Controller as Controller;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

 class ResettingFOSUser1Controller extends Controller
 {
    public function sendEmailAction()
    {
        $result = array('success' => false,
                    "error"=> true,
                    "data" => "1" 
        );
        $response = new Response(json_encode($result));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.
Help me Please!

Answer (score 0):

change

```
   public function getParent()
   {
    return 'FOSUserBundle';
   }
```

to

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'SonataUserBundle';
}
```